# How do I send an HTML email?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have successfully sent email in my web application using JMS, but the result only displays in plain text. I want the content to be able to display html. How do I do it? Here is roughly what I have:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
try{
    msg.setSubject("Test Notification");
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(sentTo, false));
    String message = "<div style=\"color:red;\">BRIDGEYE</div>";
    msg.setText(message);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    Transport.send(msg);
}catch(MessagingException me){
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "sendEmailNotification: {0}", me.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 283, accepted):

As per the Javadoc, the [`MimeMessage#setText()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) sets a default mime type of `text/plain`, while you need `text/html`. Rather use [`MimeMessage#setContent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

For additional details, see:

- [GMail Media Queries](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design?utm_campaign=gmail_updates&utm_source=pardot&utm_medium=email)
- [GMail CSS Design](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)
- [CSS support in mail clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Thanks, at first I did not read carefully, I have setText and setContent together, so it does not work, but now after taking out setText(), it work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Set content type. Look at this [method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
message.setContent("<h1>Hello</h1>", "text/html");
```

Comment: For Groovy. [Don't forget to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262161/how-to-modify-the-mime-message-in-editable-email-plugin-in-jenkins/49126212#49126212) `GString` to `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Google app engine/Java, then use the following...

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, "Admin"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 new InternetAddress(toAddress, "user");

msg.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(message, "text/html");
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
msg.setContent(mp);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: `msg.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");` does not work. It should be `msg.setSubject(subject);`

Comment: @FizerKhan - really? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: does not work. It should be

`msg.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8"); `
and 
`htmlPart.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Answer (score 7):

Since JavaMail version 1.4, there is an overload of [`setText`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method that accepts the subtype.

```
// Passing null for second argument in order for the method to determine
// the actual charset on-the fly.
// If you know the charset, pass it. "utf-8" should be fine
msg.setText( message, null, "html" );
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to call

```
msg.saveChanges();
```

after setting content type.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/email/ they have an HtmlEmail class that probably does exactly what you need.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete and very simple java class for sending emails using Google(gmail) account here,
[Send email message using java application](http://lasanthals.blogspot.com/2013/09/send-email-using-java-and-google-account.html)

It uses following properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Comment: This doesn't at all address the question. The OP was asking to send specifically HTML emails.

Answer (score 0):

The "loginVo.htmlBody(messageBodyPart);" will contain the html formatted designed information, but in mail does not receive it.

JAVA - STRUTS2

```
package com.action;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.bo.LoginBo;
import com.manager.AttendanceManager;
import com.manager.LoginManager;
import com.manager.SSLEmail;
import com.vo.AttendanceManagementVo;
import com.vo.LeaveManagementVo;
import com.vo.LoginVo;
import com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.Message;
import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeBodyPart;

public class InsertApplyLeaveAction implements Action {
private AttendanceManagementVo attendanceManagementVo;

public AttendanceManagementVo getAttendanceManagementVo() {
    return attendanceManagementVo;
}

public void setAttendanceManagementVo(
        AttendanceManagementVo attendanceManagementVo) {
    this.attendanceManagementVo = attendanceManagementVo;
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    String empId=attendanceManagementVo.getEmpId();
    String leaveType=attendanceManagementVo.getLeaveType();
    String leaveStartDate=attendanceManagementVo.getLeaveStartDate();
    String leaveEndDate=attendanceManagementVo.getLeaveEndDate();
    String reason=attendanceManagementVo.getReason();
    String employeeName=attendanceManagementVo.getEmployeeName();
    String manageEmployeeId=empId;
    float totalLeave=attendanceManagementVo.getTotalLeave();
    String leaveStatus=attendanceManagementVo.getLeaveStatus();
//  String approverId=attendanceManagementVo.getApproverId();
    attendanceManagementVo.setEmpId(empId);
    attendanceManagementVo.setLeaveType(leaveType);
    attendanceManagementVo.setLeaveStartDate(leaveStartDate);
    attendanceManagementVo.setLeaveEndDate(leaveEndDate);
    attendanceManagementVo.setReason(reason);
    attendanceManagementVo.setManageEmployeeId(manageEmployeeId);
    attendanceManagementVo.setTotalLeave(totalLeave);
    attendanceManagementVo.setLeaveStatus(leaveStatus);
    attendanceManagementVo.setEmployeeName(employeeName);

    AttendanceManagementVo attendanceManagementVo1=new AttendanceManagementVo();
    AttendanceManager attendanceManager=new AttendanceManager();    
    attendanceManagementVo1=attendanceManager.insertLeaveData(attendanceManagementVo);
    attendanceManagementVo1=attendanceManager.getApproverId(attendanceManagementVo);
    String approverId=attendanceManagementVo1.getApproverId();
    String approverEmployeeName=attendanceManagementVo1.getApproverEmployeeName();
    LoginVo loginVo=new LoginVo();
    LoginManager loginManager=new LoginManager();
    loginVo.setEmpId(approverId);
    loginVo=loginManager.getEmailAddress(loginVo);
    String emailAddress=loginVo.getEmailAddress();
    String subject="LEAVE IS SUBMITTED FOR AN APPROVAL BY THE  - " +employeeName;
//  String body =   "Hi "+approverEmployeeName+" ," + "\n" + "\n" +
//          leaveType+" is Applied for "+totalLeave+" days by the  " +employeeName+ "\n" + "\n" +
//          " Employee Name: " + employeeName +"\n" +
//          " Applied Leave Type: " + leaveType +"\n" +
//          " Total Days: " + totalLeave +"\n" + "\n" +
  //        " To view Leave History, Please visit the employee poratal or copy and paste the below link in your browser: " + "\n" +  

  //        " NOTE : This is an automated message. Please do not reply."+ "\n" +  "\n" +                        

    Session session = null;

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    String htmlText = ("<div style=\"color:red;\">BRIDGEYE</div>");
    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

    loginVo.setHtmlBody(messageBodyPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);
    Transport.send(message);


    loginVo.setSubject(subject);
//  loginVo.setBody(body);
    loginVo.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
    SSLEmail sSSEmail=new SSLEmail();
    sSSEmail.sendEmail(loginVo);
    return "success";
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way not sure it works for all the CSS primitives

By setting the header property "Content-Type" to "text/html"

```
mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

now I can do stuff like

```
mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

mimeMessage.setText ("`<html><body><h1 style =\"color:blue;\">My first Header<h1></body></html>`")
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setText(java.lang.String text,
                    boolean html)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText-java.lang.String-boolean-) from `MimeMessageHelper`:

```
MimeMessage mimeMsg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper msgHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMsg, false, "utf-8");
boolean isHTML = true;
msgHelper.setText("<h1>some html</h1>", isHTML);
```

But you need to:

```
mimeMsg.saveChanges();
```

Before:

```
javaMailSender.send(mimeMsg);
```