# Create a HTML Email from Java

Tags: java, html, json, jakarta-mail

I had a jSON Object which i have parsed using JSON-Java library,
Now i want to put the relevant content as a HTML table and circulate using email.
Please suggest the best and neat approach to do so,
Also, please point to any resources the may be interesting.

Thanks

Comment: Googling for "Java mail" would lead you to ... JavaMail. Follow the links, and you'll find tutorials explaining how to send HTML mails. In particular, this one: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailSending

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send html email via Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create variable "body" and store in it code for HTML Table created using  tags.
Visit w3chools.com for more information about HTML Table. You can use tools like Dreamweaver also if u want to create table with rich graphics and copy the code to variable.

Then you have to do is convert static table into dynamic to use json Parsed Values. Just replace static values and use loops to generate multiple rows.

Good an Easy Tutorial on sending HTML Emails is available at 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaMail to create a MIME-email with a text/html attachment, and then put your HTML in there.  Configure JavaMail with the recipient, subject, SMTP-server etc, and ask it to send the mail.

Comment: Thanks for the java mail help, How would you suggest to generate HTML Content within my Java program.. I have a parsed a huge json file and saved them as Json Array and values..

Comment: I would probably transform the JSON structure into a real Java object, and use a template engine like freemarker.