# How do I send an html email with JavaMail?

Tags: java, html, email, smtp, mime

I've already tried the charset suggestion at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java)

But the email shows up with the exact value of messageText... not rendering any of the HTML.

Here is my current code

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

String messageText = "<br/>THIS IS A TEST...<br/>!!!";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(true);
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setSubject(messageSubject);
message.setContent(messageText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Address[] fromAddress = InternetAddress.parse ( "pleasedonotreplymessage@[removed]" ) ; 
message.addFrom( fromAddress );

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddress));

transport.connect("[removed]", "", "");
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
transport.close();
```

I would prefer **not** to have to install other parties tools.. which would require a complete rework of my current code.

Comment: It is best to use tested and credible frameworks if they are available. Unless you want to learn how to write such a framework by yourself :-)

Comment: But the JavaMail API is pretty core to Java its-self... and extensively used.  Also doesn't require extra installations, configuration and/or setup of a different tool.  Right?

Answer (score 2):

This is tested and confirmed to work.

There are more elegant structures to use for an HTML email that are supported by a wider array of email clients, but for a quick solution this works in the readers I've tested (Outlook, Android mail client connected to Exchange, and Gmail).

```
public static void sendHtmlEmail(String server, String from, String to, String cc, String subject, String htmlBody) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", server);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(from);
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, to);
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, cc);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
    part.setText(htmlBody);
    mp.addBodyPart(part);
    msg.setContent(mp);

    // Content type has to be set after the message is put together
    // Then saveChanges() must be called for it to take effect
    part.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    msg.saveChanges();

    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thymeleaf to render rich HTML email and send it with Spring Mail utilities.

Tutorial: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

Tutorial source code: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail

Answer (score 0):

use [Javamail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

[Here is an Example](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/how-to-send-mail-with-javamail-and-tomcat)

Comment: Aren't I already using this?  The link you provided uses "Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);" which is exactly what I have.  It also uses "Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();" and I have exactly that...?