# Html mail sent with Spring's JavaMailSender is without subject and plain-text

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail, html-email

I am trying to send an html email inside a Spring (version 3.0.5.RELEASE)  webapp using Spring's `JavaMailSenderImpl`.

The emails are sent but they are incorrect:

- they are missing the subject
- the To field is shown empty or as "Undisclosed recipients:;"
- the html body is shown as plain text

I have tried the following, without success:

```java
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false, "utf-8");

message.setTo(to);
message.setFrom(from);
message.setReplyTo(from);
message.setSubject(StringUtils.trim(subject));                       
message.setSentDate(new Date());

mimeMessage.setContent(StringUtils.trim(messageBody), "text/html");

mailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage);
```

(`mailSender`is Spring's JavaMailSenderImpl retrieved from application context; `to`, `from`, `subject`, `messageBody` are `String` objects).

To set the content, I also tried:

```
message.setText(messageBody, true);
message.setText(messageBodyPlain, messageBodyText);
```

I also tried using a multipart message (setting `MimeMessageHelper`'s second argument to `true`) and with a `MimeMessagePreparator`.

Looking at the delivered messages, they do not contain the `Content-Type:` or `Subject` headers.

For my tests I have used my company's smtp server and Gmail's smtp server.

**UPDATE: problem solved**

Turns out my question is a duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786239/why-does-this-java-mail-arrive-as-plain-text-instead-of-html-at-recipient): a bunch of Maven dependencies included `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec`, and this was the cause of malformed emails. I just had to exclude this jar, editing pom.xml like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8</version>
    <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try with `MimeMessagePreparator`?

Comment: Yes, I tried also with `MimeMessagePreparator`,  same result

Answer (score 0):

try to create the MimeMessageHelper with multipart flag set to true;

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "utf-8");
```

Comment: yes, I already tried that (I have update the question to specify this).