# how to make java string bold and colored

Tags: java, email, html-email

I am developing email application using java. I have a string as follows :

```
String msg= "College Email \nHello"+" "+name+"\n"+"You are selected As 'Admin'.\n Please use Given username and password for login\n \Username:"+" "+username+" "+"Password:"+" "+password+"";
```

I want send this string as email message. and i want to "**BOLD** and color" username and password(I want to show this message in inbox i.e on browser). how can i embed HTML tags to do this ? OR is there any simple way to do this without using HTML tags ?

Can any one correct above string (msg) OR provide any link or code to fix this problem ?

thank you.

Comment: You should use html in your email

Comment: agreed too, the body of message can be taken between HTML and plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type the tags into your message like `String msg = "<strong>Hello World!</strong>` and send it as a HTML message, you only need to set type of the content via `MimeMessage#setContent()` method like

```
message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");`
```

Comment: hi petr ...how can i instantiate MimeMessage ?? is it like this : MimeNessage message =new MimeMessage(arg0); message.setContent(msg,"....") Actully arg0 is required as argument.. How can i do this ??

Comment: Just do `Message msg = new MimeMessage(yourSession)`;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the old school, vanilla java way you can use the `org.w3c.dom.Document` API to get the work done.

It has a bunch of useful methods for creating and manipulating elements such as `createElement`, `createAttribute`, etc. to do what you want.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

Answer (score 1):

As per the **Javadoc**, the [MimeMessage#setText()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) sets a default mime type of `text/plain`, while you need text/html. Rather use [MimeMessage#setContent()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
String someHtmlMessage = "Hello this is test message <b style='color:blue;'>bold color</b>";

message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Note that the HTML should not contain the `<html>, <head> or <body>`. Gmail will ignore it. See also CSS support in mail clients.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java - little big copypasta, don't you think?:-)

Comment: Yes but it is changed something which in question he want.