# send html page with hyperlink as mail using java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a html page as mail using javamail.
my html page contains a link

```
<a href>click here</a>
```

when i am sending the mail the link is showing as a plain text.what should i do? here is the code i used

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);    
message.setSubject("modified html page","text/html");    
message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");    
message.setText(html, "utf-8");    
message.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

please give me a suggestion.

Comment: FYI [`setText`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.0/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.java#MimeMessage.setText%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) does nothing here. `setText` internally calls `setContent`. Try removing it, see if you get better results.

Answer (score 2):

Danny rightly points out [setText](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.0/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.java#MimeMessage.setText%28java.lang.String%29) internally calls `setContent` so what you are doing here is entirely redundant. 
Only this would be enough :-

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);    
message.setSubject("modified html page","text/html");        
message.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Also `setContent` internally calls

```
removeHeader("Content-Type");
removeHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding");
```

So there is no point calling `message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");` as it would be removed anyway.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068907/3107043) answer on more details on how to send HTML emails

Comment: And note that how the message is displayed is up to the mail reader.  Maybe your mail reader is not displaying the link because there's no value for the href attribute?