# Sending an email in HTML format

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, smtp

I would like to send an email with HTML table format.

I am trying to send an email in HTML format. It's working fine when I run through **Eclipse IDE**. But when I try to run through **Apache Tomcat Directory**(put the project inside WebApp folder and then run the server) then it send the email which shows the html code, it doesn't shows the rich text itself.

**Java Code:**

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                        String mail = (String) recipientMails.nextElement();
                        // System.out.println(mail);

                        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mail));

                        message.setSubject(subject + " -: " + submission.getSubmissionName());

                        message.setContent(htmTemp + "<tr><td>" + submission.getSubmissionName() + "</td><td>" + submission.getStatus() + "</td><td>" + messg + "</td></tr>" + "</table></body></html>", "test/html");

                        logger.error(subject + "SendTo:" + recipientMail + "\n" + messg);

                        Transport.send(message);
```

**Actual Output: (which comes wrong when running through Tomcat Directory)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>![enter image description here][1]
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Submission Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr><tr><td>ELQ_1423749204038</td><td>Sent For Translation</td><td>Your submission has been sent successfully for translation.</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

**Expected Output:(which comes fine when running through Eclipse IDE)**

See the below image:

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in you're mime type. Should read `text/html` not `test/html` in the line `message.setContent(...`

Comment: May http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java is helpful. There are some comments regarding this problem.