# Using PrimeFaces editor to enter email body in java, but it sends html tags in email body?

Tags: primefaces, editor

Text entered: `hey piko.`

sent in mail is as:

```
"hey<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><span style="text-decoration: underline line-through;">piko</span></div>"
```

Comment: Removed the extraneous bullets that weren't used and formatted the code so the reader can see what happened. There's not much detail here, this question could use some additional supporting facts (or someone that knows what you are talking about!)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PrimeFaces `<p:editor/>` is an input component for formatted text. The formatting is done via HTML.

If you do not want formatted text, use another input component for the input like `<p:inputTextera>` instead. 
See: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml

If you want the user to be able to send formatted text, send an HTML mail. See this question for more information about that topic:
 [How do I send an HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java)