# Send email with html template in java

Tags: java, templates, jakarta-mail

I have an html email template which generates a view as shown in the [attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuzFc.png), the html template has an embedded CSS and html content also the logos etc.

I am able to send plain text emails, I can add required html tags create tables etc and the email goes fine, but i need to know how can i bind data to the html template with embeded css and logos to send out emails.
I am using  javax.mail and amazon ses.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java

Comment: I receive the html part in the email but the css content and logo image is not coming properly, I am not sure how can I bind the dynamic data inside it.

Comment: You can use base64 data of your image into the img tag and for css please don't use css using url, just directly provide the style to the html component.

Comment: There are limits to the css support in email clients; see [this document](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).