# Sending dynamic contents in java email API (Repeating Data)

Tags: java, html, email-templates

My need is I want to use any kind of loop in `setContent()` but as it is a method, I am not allowed to do this. So do you have any alternate method for doing this?

Look into my code below

```
String to = ""; //change accordingly

//Get the session object  
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");                            

Session sessions = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
{
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("", ""); //change accordingly  
    }  
});         

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sessions);  
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("")); //change accordingly  
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  
message.setSubject("sai");       
message.setContent("Here we can pass html format including css","text/html");

Transport.send(message);
```

Can anyone please tell me that how can I pass dynamic content in `message.setContent()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-an-html-email)

Comment: My question is different sir, What I want to do, I just want to pass dynamic contents in setContent(). Moreover my need is I want to use any kind of loop in setContent() but as it is a method, I am not allowed to do this. So do you  have any alternate method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for velocity template engine:

[Velocity Email Templates * Link 1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/UseVelocitytogenerateHTMLbasedemail.htm)

[Velocity Email Templates * Link 2](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html)