# how send html tag in java email class?

Tags: java

i want to send below mentioned results to email and want to receive them in email carefully. therefore i decide to use html code, but no  result.

caputure.png image[image: Result what i receive:]

Code:

public static void  sendresult (  ShowResultModel showuserresulttable) {

```
    final String username = *****
    final String password = ******;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mekteb48@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("iismayilov028@gmail.com"));

        message.setSubject("Exammer result :" + showuserresulttable.getUsername() );

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

         String MESSAGE = " ";
        double resultpercent  =  showuserresulttable.getScore() /(double) showuserresulttable.getTotalanswer()*100;

        MESSAGE+="<b>Username:</b> " + showuserresulttable.getUsername() + "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Subject</b>" + showuserresulttable.getSubject() + "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Variant :</b>" + showuserresulttable.getVariant() +   "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Score of result:</b>" + showuserresulttable.getScore() + "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Total question :</b>" + showuserresulttable.getTotalanswer()+ "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b> Score percent:</b>" + resultpercent + "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Spendtime:</b>" + showuserresulttable.getSpendtime() + "second" + "<br><hr>";
        MESSAGE+="<b>Examdate:</b>" + showuserresulttable.getExamdate() ;

        message.setText(MESSAGE);
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Mail gonderildi!");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-an-html-email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `message.setText(MESSAGE);` you should use  `message.setText(MESSAGE, true);` `here true` is represent `html` (whether to apply content type "text/html" for an HTML mail, using default content type ("text/plain") else)

Also if you are using thymeleaf or freemarker then u can used there template.

Comment: i try to what do you advice, but when i write true in class i get red underline error, "Set text string in part cannot be applied", what to do?

Comment: Do you user spring javacv mail dependency or else ?

Comment: i dont use spring. i have coded in ide intellejis ,  imported below mentioned jars:   import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

Comment: Please add this line. 'message.setContent(MESSAGE, "text/html; charset=utf-8");' also please remove message.setText (message):; line

Comment: Please add this line. 'message.setContent(MESSAGE, "text/html; charset=utf-8");' also please remove message.setText (message):; line

Comment: i try , but got error again  : String can be applied in part  to String, java.lang.String   :-(

Comment: Do you mean by this line message.setContent(MESSAGE, "text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?

Comment: great job, thanks a lot, i did it . i am greatful to you.