# Send data from java mail in HTML Table

Tags: java

I am trying to send data from my Java mail application in the form of a HTML table. The problem is that when I receive the mail, the data is in simple text format and not in a table form. Please suggest a solution

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(200);
sb1.append("<html><body>"+ "<table style='border:2px solid black'>");
for(SCSINPojo cat : ar){

    sb1.append("<tr>");
    sb1.append(cat.getINNumber())
       .append("<td>")
       .append(cat.getDescription())
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(cat.getStatus())
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(cat.getStatus())
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(cat.getOwner())
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(cat.getOwnerGroup())
       .append("</td><td>")
       .append(cat.getSeverity());
    sb1.append("</tr>");
    String in = sb1.toString();

}
sb1.append("</table></body></html>");

message.setText(sb1.toString());

Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-an-html-email

Comment: String in is very useless because it is never used and re-write at each iteration

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
MimeMessage simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
```

Then, when you want to set the message body, either call

```
simpleMessage.setText(text, "utf-8", "html");
```

or call

```
simpleMessage.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...you can even print it out to an HTML file and so I have added some break lines for appearance.

```
sb1.append("<html><body><br/>"+ "<table style='border:2px solid black'><br/>");
    for(SCSINPojo cat : ar){

        sb1.append("<tr><br/><td>");
        sb1.append(cat.getINNumber())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getDescription())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getStatus())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getStatus())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getOwner())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getOwnerGroup())
           .append("</td><br/><td>")
           .append(cat.getSeverity());
        sb1.append("</td><br/><td>");
        String in = sb1.toString();

    }
    sb1.append("</table></br></body></html>");
```